# ssh tunnel to server running on cluster compute node

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, ssh-tunnel

I have a script to launch Jupyter Notebook server running on a particular node of our cluster, and need to be able to access the running instance from a local windows machine (browser interface).  The ssh commands are handled through paramiko, and I'd like a similarly pythonic way of creating the tunnels, rather than just a system call. I am trying out sshtunnel, which is, unfortunately, my current stumbling block.

I need to create two tunnels as outlined below. For clarity, HOME is the windows machine, HOST is the cluster head-node, and NODE is the particular node on which the server is running.

The server is bound to localhost, by default at port 8888. The ports underneath HOME and HOST are arbitrary, I just use them for illustration (in reality, the most convenient HOME port is also 8888)

```
[HOME] <------> [HOST] <------> [NODE]
 1111            2222            8888
```

I know the code below is incomplete and just plain wrong, as I can't figure out how to correctly combine the local/remote bindings. Right now I don't know if I'm barking up the wrong tree - the docs suggest that I can create both tunnels in a single pass, but do I need two separate instances?

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

t1 = SSHTunnelForwarder(
     ('headnode.server', 22),
     ssh_username='meagain',
     ssh_pkey='~/.ssh/id_rsa',
     local_bind_address = ('localhost',1111),
     remote_bind_addresses =[ ('localhost',2222), ('compute.node',8888)])
t1.start()
```

edit: trying out option 2, as outlined below. The config is set up and working fine on the command-line using an SSH client. For reference, this is under Anaconda with python 3.6, on a Windows 7 machine (hence the additional file-path wrangling below)

```
print(sshtunnel.__version__)
'0.1.0'
print(paramiko.__version__)
'2.1.2'



t1 = sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    NODE,
    ssh_username=USER,
    ssh_pkey=paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(os.path.expanduser(os.path.normpath('~/.ssh/id_rsa'))),
    ssh_proxy_enabled=True,  # DEFAULT
    ssh_config_file=os.path.expanduser(os.path.normpath('~/.ssh/config')),  # if rather than default
    local_bind_address=('localhost', 1111),
    remote_bind_address=('localhost', 8889)
)
t1.start()
```

logs:

```
2017-04-06 12:28:25,523| INF | MainThrea/0981@sshtunnel | 0 keys loaded from agent
    t1.start()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sshtunnel.py", line 1224, in start
    reason='Could not establish session to SSH gateway')
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sshtunnel.py", line 1036, in _raise
    raise exception(reason)
sshtunnel.BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not establish session to SSH gateway
>>> 2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport | paramiko.ssh_exception.ProxyCommandFailure: ('ssh HOST -W NODE:22', 'An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket')
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport | 
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR | MainThrea/1076@sshtunnel | Could not connect to gateway NODE:22 : ssh HOST -W NODE:22
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Bioinformatics\Scripts\bsub_jupyter\tunneller.py", line 234, in <module>
2017-04-06 12:28:25,523| INF | MainThrea/0901@sshtunnel | Connecting to gateway: NODE:22 as user 'USER'
2017-04-06 12:28:25,523| DEB | MainThrea/0904@sshtunnel | Concurrent connections allowed: True
2017-04-06 12:28:25,523| DEB | MainThrea/1284@sshtunnel | Trying to log in with key: b'1e44a013d97d417e4900025c6c11d073'
2017-04-06 12:28:25,523| DEB | MainThrea/1047@sshtunnel | Connecting via proxy: 'HOST'
2017-04-06 12:28:25,523| ERR |  Thread-2/1572@transport | Exception: ('ssh HOST -W NODE:22', 'An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket')
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport | Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport |   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\proxy.py", line 96, in recv
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport |     [self.process.stdout], [], [], select_timeout)
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport | OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport | 
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport | 
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport | Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport |   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1749, in run
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport |     self._check_banner()
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport |   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1893, in _check_banner
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport |     buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport |   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 331, in readline
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport |     buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport |   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 485, in _read_timeout
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport |     x = self.__socket.recv(128)
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport |   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\proxy.py", line 107, in recv
2017-04-06 12:28:25,538| ERR |  Thread-2/1570@transport |     raise ProxyCommandFailure(' '.join(self.cmd), e.strerror)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since port 8888 is bound to localhost as you mention, it won't be reachable from HOST. If that's the case, you have two options:

## Option A

Use sshtunnel's `ssh_proxy` parameter:

```
proxy = paramiko.ProxyCommand('ssh HOST -l USER -i IDENTITY_FILE -W headnode.server:22')
t1 = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (NODE, 22),
    ssh_username='meagain',
    ssh_pkey='~/.ssh/id_rsa',
    ssh_proxy=proxy,
    local_bind_address=('localhost', 1111),
    remote_bind_addresses=('localhost', 8888)
)
```

## Option B

Use ssh configuration file.

You need to have a valid configuration file with a `ProxyCommand` entry for `NODE` such as:

```
Host HOST
    User HOSTUSER
    IdentityFile HOSTUSER_PKEY
Host NODE
    ProxyCommand ssh HOST -W %h:%p
```

Then, open the tunnel and let it read the `ProxyCommand` entry:

```
t1 = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (NODE, 22),
    ssh_username='meagain',
    ssh_pkey='~/.ssh/id_rsa',
    ssh_proxy_enabled=True,  # DEFAULT
    ssh_config_file='/path/to/your-config-file',  # if rather than default
    local_bind_address=('localhost', 1111),
    remote_bind_addresses=('localhost', 8888)
)
```

Comment: Am trying out option 2, as I had been meaning to set up the config file anyway. It's working just fine on the command-line. Unfortunately it's throwing an error that it can't connect to the ssh gateway. I think I've narrowed it down to the ProxyCommand - when configuring a paramiko client that has a proxy, I'm getting this back : ``paramiko.ssh_exception.ProxyCommandFailure: ('ssh HOST -W NODE:22', 'An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket')``

Comment: for reference, here's the config: ``
Host HOST
 Hostname HOSTIPADDRESS
 User USER
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host NODE
 User USER
 ProxyCommand ssh HOST  -W %h:%p
``

Comment: can you set `debug_level="DEBUG"` and post it in the question? Same for your versions (`[l.__version__ for l in [paramiko, sshtunnel]]`)

Comment: Please install sshtunnel from git and retry